# can't able to find Error: Syntax error below code

Tags: formula, compile-error

```
IF
(
ISNEW() 
Garage__r.Total_inventory__c < Unit_Solds__c,
IF (Unit_Solds__c< PRIORVALUE(Unit_Solds__c),false,
Garage__r.Total_inventory__c<(Unit_Solds__c-PRIORVALUE(Unit_Solds__c))))
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot a comma after ISNEW()

```
IF
(
  ISNEW(), //Eval
    Garage__r.Total_inventory__c < Unit_Solds__c, //True Part
    IF ( //False Part
     Unit_Solds__c < PRIORVALUE(Unit_Solds__c), //eval
      false, //true part
      Garage__r.Total_inventory__c < (Unit_Solds__c-PRIORVALUE(Unit_Solds__c)) //false part
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

False part of the first IF is missing.

[image]

I have pointed out issues as yellow highlights.

Comment: ISNEW **DOES NOT** take any parameters. It solely evaluates to true if the record is being inserted

Comment: Ohh..that was a bummer..thanks for pointing out @Eric. Updated solution accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: It is still incorrect as you are making the same mistake as the OP